# Can't configure env variables to use cloudinary in react app

Tags: reactjs, netlify, cloudinary, dotenv

I'm having problems with cloudinary configurations in my react app. I installed the library and created a cloudinary file like this:

cloudinary.js

```js
import { v2 as cloudinary } from 'cloudinary';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUD_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUD_API_SECRET,
    secure: true
});

export default cloudinary;
```

My .env file:

```
CLOUD_NAME=d*******c
CLOUD_API_KEY=8***********8
CLOUD_API_SECRET=j*************************A
```

I'm using netlify to deploy. When I'm trying to use cloudinary in other file with `import cloudinary from "...";` I'm getting an error like below:
[image]

Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try adding your env setting in the: 'Site Settings' -> 'Build & Deploy' and scroll down to 'Environment'. Additionally, you may need to use the prefix `REACT_APP_XXXXX` in react app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you used for setting up the project.

- If it's CRA then you have to use `REACT_APP_` as the prefix, [Reference](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)
- If it's Vite then you have to use `import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY` with `VITE_` as the prefix, [Reference](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html)

Comment: Yes I'm using Vite, but I already have other variables in my .env file, for database (faunadb) and JWT, and they are wokring nicely. The only difference is that I only use those variables within netlify/serverless functions through an import, and the cloudinary import was made inside a file I created to serve as a middleware, with axios requests. That's what is wrong? Or there is a way that I can use it inside my middleware file?

Comment: If you require `cloudinary` to be used from react components then variables should be set with `VITE_` prefix otherwise if its used in `netlify serverless` middleware then I think netlify env variables should do.